# jupyter notebook ipywidgets not showing (no error)

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ipywidgets

I recently set up a new Conda environment and brought up previously working codes
However, I found out that Jupyter widget does not seem to work properly

I did below things

```
conda install -c conda-forge ipywidgets

jupyter nbextension enable --py widgetsnbextension --sys-prefix
```

Could anyone tell me what am I missing??

```
from ipywidgets import widgets, Layout, Textarea, IntSlider, RadioButtons
transcripted = widgets.Textarea("hello", layout=Layout(width='100%', display='inline-flex', flex_flow = 'row wrap'))
submit_button = widgets.Button(description="submit")

display(transcripted)
display(submit_button)
```

the result is as below

```
Textarea(value='hello', layout=Layout(display='inline-flex', flex_flow='row wrap', width='100%'))
Button(description='submit', style=ButtonStyle())
```

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uPmLx.png)

Comment: Maybe you had some other module(s) installed and this module was displaying elemens in different way.

Answer (score 1):

First, Save your work and close the notebook. 
Just run following command on cmd with run as administrator.

`conda install -c conda-forge ipywidgets`

It will also enable the extension for you 
(No need of run `jupyter nbextension enable --py widgetsnbextension --sys-prefix`)

After installing restart the notebook. It will fix your issue.

Refer to [this](https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user_install.html) as well!

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own qustion.

(I am not administrator)
I asked administrator to stop the jupyter notebook server and start it again.

After that it worked.